# Django rest framework how to delete a model through it's serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have such a scenario where I want to delete the saved model through its serializer:

```
class SomeView(APIView):
  ...
  def post(self, request, context):
    serializer = MySerializer(data = request.data)
    # I need to save the model since I need the file field in the following processings
    if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
    try:
      ...
    except:
      # I need to delete the model in case of exception
      serializer.delete()
```

But there seems not to exist a way to delete the saved model through its serializer because I got this error `AttributeError: 'VideoSerializer' object has no attribute 'delete'`

Comment: delete the model? or delete the *model instance* ?

Comment: Delete the instance. I think it not possible to delete the instance through serializer. what I did is to `model = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=serializer.data['pk'])` , then `model.delete()`

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't do the `try-except-block` before saving the object, instead of trying to delete after saving?

Comment: @Shameless I need to read the file uploaded with the request, if I don't save it, I won't be able to read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `serializer.save()` returns the saved object.

```
instance = None
if serializer.is_valid():
  instance = serializer.save()
try:
  ...
except:
  instance.delete()
```

That should delete the object being saved.